# Python how to extract variables from expression

Tags: python, regex

Sorry i am new to python. I am trying to extract variables from expression like:

```
ABC=DEF=5
C=DF/10
```

i want to extract ABC,DEF,C,DF etc.

Comment: If you say you are trying, please include what you have tried?

Comment: The answer depends on the syntax, e.g. on what the variable names are accepted and whether string literals are allowed in expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for the example you have given, it will of course fail for more complex code.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '''ABC=DEF=5
C=DF/10'''
>>> re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z_]\w*', text)
['ABC', 'DEF', 'C', 'DF']
```

Comment: Yes he is right i tried this at myself import re
>>> text = "ABC=B=4"
>>> re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z_]\w*', text)
['ABC', 'B']

Comment: how to extract operators (+,=) etc at the same time.

Comment: @user2217267 That would be a different question. Although you should attempt it yourself